# What is the error in this code? Duplicate records found in Database.

Tags: java, mysql

I want the quantity to be updated in the database when a new item with the same type is added. Quantity is updated but a new record is saved each time it's updated. I am using mysql query browser and netbeans to develop this software.

```
ResultSet rs=DB.createConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("select * from orders where status=('"+1+"')");

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("DB True");

            do{

            System.out.println("in_While");
            int dctno=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ctno"));
            int dctype=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ctype"));
            int dqty=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("qty"));

            int nw_qty=dqty+qty;

            if (dctno==ctno && dctype==ctype) {
                System.out.println("Equals/Stock ctype= "+ctype);
                DB.createConnection().createStatement().executeUpdate("update orders set qty=('"+nw_qty+"') where ctno=('"+ctno+"') and ctype=('"+ctype+"')");

                System.out.println("DB Updated");
                txtQuantity.setText("");
                dt.setRowCount(0);

            }else{
                System.out.println("Not");
                DB.createConnection().createStatement().executeUpdate("insert into orders(ctno,ctype,qty,date,status) values('"+ctno+"','"+ctype+"','"+qty+"','"+txtlDate.getText()+"','"+1+"')");

            }

           System.out.println("end_While");  

            }while (rs.next());
```

Comment: you are inserting instead of updating

Comment: Whats your question - at which line you are getting errors? what is your table schema? This is perfect case for eclipse debugging.

Comment: Never, ever, EVER put values directly into query strings. Use placeholders and set the values with Prepared Statements, and google SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: You mean sql parameters.

Comment: You can do all this in *one* SQL statement: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. You're looping over your entire result set, and executing an action for every record in the set.

So, let's say you have 3 rows, one that matches your criteria, and two that don't. In that case, one record will be updated **and** two new ones will be inserted.

To fix it, you should:

1. Execute a query that retrieves only the record that you might want to update.
2. If such a record was found, update it.
3. If no record was found, insert a new record.

---

On a side note, a couple of additional comments/remarks:

- Why store all your values as strings in your database and convert them to numbers in your application. Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just store numbers in your database?
- As noted in the comments: use prepared statements instead of string concatenation to build your queries.
- You can reuse your connections. There's no need to create a new connection for every query you execute.

Comment: My suggestions are listed in 3 points in my answer. Right where it says: *To fix it, you should: ...*

Comment: Thank You. Answer is very clear and helpful.